# Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Candidate list as a parent and Candidate as a child.
On Candidate list there is a Select All input so i bind function to it to set state if candidates are being selected and passing that state to child.
That one part works but those inputs are not mutable by itself just by parent Select All can be changed.

**This is what does it looks like:**
[image]

**CandidateList Component(Parent):**

```
class CandidateList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      candidateList: null,
      candidateSelected: false
    }
  }

  onSelectCandidatesClick() {
    this.setState({
      candidateSelected: !this.state.candidateSelected
    });
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="CandidateList">
        <div className="__selection">
          <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onClick={() => this.onSelectCandidatesClick()}/>
          <label htmlFor="selectAll"><span id="__label">Select All</span></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Candidate Component(Child):**

```
class Candidate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      candidateSelected: false
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      candidateSelected: nextProps.selectCandidate
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Candidate">
        <div className="__select">
          <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="candidate" data-candidate-id={this.props.candidateData.id} checked={this.state.candidateSelected} />
          <label htmlFor="candidate"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for all suggestions and help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the checked value of the child based on the props.candidateSelected (if the select all was selected from the parent) 
or based on the state (if the checkbox was selected from the child)

You have to add an onclick event handler that will change the state when the checkbox in the child is clicked

```
class Candidate extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      candidateSelected: false
    }
  }

  onSelectCandidatesClick() {
    this.setState({
      candidateSelected: !this.state.candidateSelected
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Candidate">
        <div className="__select">
          <input className="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="candidate" data-candidate-id={this.props.candidateData.id} 
          onClick={() => this.onSelectCandidatesClick()}
          checked={this.state.candidateSelected || this.props.candidateSelected} />
          <label htmlFor="candidate"></label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to give the checkbox input in your child component a way to process its change based on an input event.

```
<input checked={this.state.candidateSelected} onChange={e => {}} />
```

At the moment you're passing props in to say if it's checked or not so it can be an empty function.

Personally I think this is the wrong approach in any case. It's not an input because the user isn't inputting anything directly to that element.

Maybe you should have a prop called `checked` and if it is checked then show a check **icon** rather than an input.

```
{ this.props.checked ? <div className="checked"></div> : <div className="unchecked"></div>}
```

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set arrtibute readOnly to input tag.

```
<input type="checkbox" readOnly />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's kind of ridiculous. I have it set as `readOnly` but can still update it... Still seems better than putting an empty `onChange={e => {}}` on them all.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, but probably not the best option:

```
checked={isMenuOpen}
onClick={() => toggleDropdown()}
onChange={e => {}}
```

Comment: Yep, you can and often should have an onClick handler to select the radio, but react wants `onchange`

Answer (score -2):

Have you made custom label for all inputs?  this has gotten me before